# Calculate: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{\sin^2(x)}$.

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function. s.t. $f^\prime(0)=1$.

calculate the limit: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{\sin^2(x)}.$$

SOLUTION ATTEMPT: I thought that because $f$ is differentiable its also continuous, then we can say: $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2)=f(0)$ then, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2)-f(0)=0$ and also $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin^2(x)=0$, so using L'Hoptal's rule, we get that:

$\lim_{x\to 0 } \frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{\sin^2(x)}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f^\prime (x^2) \cdot 2x}{2\sin(x) \cdot \cos(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f^\prime (x^2) \cdot 2x}{2\sin(x) \cdot \cos(x)}$.

I reached right here and I guess I need to do another L'Hopital, is that the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{\sin^2(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{x^2-0}}{\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2-0}}$$
Observe that 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{x^2-0} = \lim_{x^2 \to 0}\dfrac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{x^2-0}  = f^{\prime}(0)$$
(notice as $x \to 0$, $x^2 \to 0$ as well) and
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2-0} = \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^2\text{.}$$
The value
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
is usually taught in a Calc. I class.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=1$, you can write
$$
f(x)=f(0)+x+o(x)
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{\sin^2x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+o(x^2)}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}=1
$$

Comment: If f is differentiable at 0, can i always assume f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)*x+o(x)?

Comment: @MrYouMath Yes, it's essentially the definition of being differentiable.

Comment: I know, but it seemed to be too powerful to me :D. Thank you for your fast response ;-).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $f(0)$ stands for a constant function in your limit. What's the derivative of a constant function?

Answer (score 1):

You are done there, since
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x^2)\cdot 2x}{2\sin x\cos x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x}{2\sin x} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x^2)}{\cos x} = 1\cdot 1 =1.$$

Comment: The hypothesis is that $f$ is differentiable; however you're using that the derivative exists in a neighborhood of zero *and* that it's continuous.